# Iptables SMTP re-routing on a proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, routing, smtp, forwarding

I'm lost... Any help would be appreciated :)

I have a mailserver. Unfortunately, the provider deny the smtp 25. I don't want to use ESMTP or a vpn.

So here is the project :
I have a dedicated server on the web with a public IP.

**SMTP Inbound part**

On this server I made these rules :

```
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING  1 -p tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination $IP
/sbin/iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -p tcp --dport 25 -d $IP -j MASQUERADE
```

Note : Because I have a dynamic IP @home, $IP is the result of a curl script.

It permit the SMTP traffic from outside to be re-routed to my mailserver, it works.

**SMTP Outbound part :**

On my mailserver, I made this rule :

```
iptables --table nat --append OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 --protocol tcp \
  --dport 25 --jump DNAT --to-destination dedicatedip:2500
```

Which forward successfully the smtp flow to the dedicated.

The point is... I don't find the correct rules on the dedicated to forward this flow to the net.
I mean, i need to re-forward the port to 25 and to forward these packets to unknow smtp servers.

I tried this on the dedicated :

```
iptables -nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 2500 --jump SNAT --to 25:37.59.121.101
```

But when the port is changed to 25 again, the packet are send @home (because of the first rules).
Is there a way to do it properly ?

Answer (score 0):

For outgoing email try using a smarthost transport on the submission port (587).  This should be allowed by your ISP.  This can connect to a minimal server on the server with the dedicated IP address.

Trying to tunnel traffic using NAT rules is unlikely to be capable of doing what you want.

If you have a server with a dedicated IP, consider using it as your server.  You can still forward the email back to your home server.  There are a number of methods you can use including `ETRN`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it seems that the submission is blocked too. I don't want to stock mails on a cloud server. I have to study the methods you mentioned.